# How to monitor an already running application in a new Bash Terminal window?

Tags: terminal, monitoring, application

An application is already running without command output, only GUi.

**How can I grab the application's command output from a new terminal window?**

Another application is already running as CLi, but I would like to monitor that specific application from a different window or even remotely without affecting the application itself?

Comment: Is it a type of application that generates log files? Do you only want to know how to do this when applications are already running, or is a case where you know beforehand alright as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very complicated for a running application. You need to attach a debugger, close the file descriptors 0, 1, and 2, open a new controllingf terminal and open the file descriptors accordingly. Probably not even this works if the app notices that it does not have a controlling terminal and thus does not use `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` the usual way, maybe even has closed them and used them for different purposes.